# Azure blob file upload using spring MVC failing

Tags: java, spring-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload files in Azure storage using spring MVC. I can upload files using java class by importing all Microsoft packages but when I try to access the same in spring I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount

I am using Spring: 4.1.1,
commons-fileupload: 1.2.2, 
commons-io:2.3
Microsoft pacakges

I am not able to find the root cause for this NoClassDefFoundError even adding all the required jars. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

@JBasu, I assume that you are using Eclipse as the Java IDE. So you can add these libraries thru drag or copy the jar files to the directory `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` (eg, see the pic below) if you created `Dynamic Web Project` for Spring MVC framework.

[image]

Or you can convert `Dynamic Web Project` to `Maven Project` thru click the right mouse button on the project title and select `Configure -> Convert to Maven Project`, then edit the `pom.xml` and add the `<dependencies>` tag to install these libraries like `azure-storage`, please see below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then Eclipse will help installing the library above & its dependent libraries.

The Azure Storage Maven library of the newest version 4.0.0 was publish at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage/4.0.0

Comment: Before posting the question I did the same what you explained. I don't see the proper packaging for the version 4.0.0 may be that was the problem then I used version 2.0.0 then it started working.  I found different packaging in both the versions.

Comment: @JBasu The Azure SDK changs along with the development of Microsoft Azure. So there have been the different packaging in the high and low versions. Please using the maven tool as far as possible to install the dependent packages to solve the incompatible and conflict problem between these packages.